# How to use LibTiff.NET Tiff2Pdf in .NET 6

Tags: .net-core, libtiff, libtiff.net, bitmiracle, tiff2pdf

I want to provide support to convert single-page and multi-page tiff files into PDFs. There is an executable in Bit Miracle's LibTiff.NET called Tiff2Pdf.

How do I use Tiff2Pdf in my application to convert tiff data stream (not a file) into a pdf data stream (not a file)?

I do not know if there is an API exposed because the documentation only lists Tiff2Pdf as a tool. I also do not see any examples in the examples folder using it in a programmatic way to determine if it can handle data streams or how to use it in my own program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libtiff tools expect a filename so the background run shown below is simply from upper right X.tif to various destinations, first is default

```
tiff2pdf x.tif
```

and we can see it writes a tiff2pdf file stream to console (Standard Output) however it failed in memory without a directory to write to. However on second run we can redirect

```
tiff2pdf x.tif > a.pdf
```

or alternately specify a destination

```
tiff2pdf -o b.pdf x.tif
```

So in order to use those tools we need a File System to receive the file objects, The destination folder/file directory can be a Memory File System drive or folder.
Thus you need to initiate that first.

[image]

NuGet is a package manager simply bundling the lib and as I don't use .net your a bit out on a limb as BitMiricle are not offering free support (hence point you at Stack Overflow, a very common tech support PLOY, Pass Liability Over Yonder) however looking at https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples
they suggest memory in some file names such as  https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/ConvertToSingleStripInMemory , perhaps get more ideas there?

Comment: Thanks for the help KJ. I am curious how I would use the utility from the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET/) in a C# application? Also, in order to follow the steps you provided, would I need to build tiff2pdf from source? I did not see a link to executables and am not very familiar with nuget other than how to add packages. Thanks!